# Splitting DataStage Output based on Key Column

Tags: etl, datastage

I have a DataStage (8.5) job that produces a CSV file as follows:

```
Key    Date        Amount
A      2014-07-24  $100
A      2014-07-23  $120
B      2014-07-24  $320
C      2014-07-24  $20
C      2014-07-23  $100
C      2014-07-22  $30
```

I would like to produce a new file with the header for each distinct Key to yield the following files from the above file:

```
Key    Date        Amount
A      2014-07-24  $100
A      2014-07-23  $120

Key    Date        Amount
B      2014-07-24  $320

Key    Date        Amount
C      2014-07-24  $20
C      2014-07-23  $100
C      2014-07-22  $30
```

The number of records for each key, and the key values themselves, will vary depending on when the job is executed.

Can this be accomplished in DataStage? If so, what would be the processing stages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Execute Command stage with the following awk statement, where key is $16:

```
awk -F "\",\"" 'NR==1 { hdr=$0; next } $16 != prev { prev=name=$16; gsub(/[^[:alnum:]_]/,"",name); $0 = hdr "\n" $0 } { print > ("/Directory/"name"_FILE.csv") }' /Directory/SOURCE_FILE.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this helps...
yo can use transformer... and Create ALL output columns as Varchar.
on key change add columns names and always pass previous values to output.

Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.